# Zoho Catalyst : Facing EXECUTION_TIME_EXCEEDED ERROR

Tags: function, serverless

I am using Zoho Catalyst for a serverless project. I'm facing EXECUTION_TIME_EXCEEDED with my Catalyst function. I'm listing the steps I followed below:

1. I created a Catalyst advanced I/O function from the CLI and added my logic as code.
2. I tried the Catalyst serve command, it throws an error saying that the execution time has been exceeded.
   `{"status":"failure","data":{"message":"applogic Execution Time Exceeded","error_code":"EXECUTION_TIME_EXCEEDED"}}` is the error I face. Please help me debug.

Answer (score 2):

Zoho Catalyst Advanced IO functions will have an execution timeout of maximum of 30 seconds. So, make sure that all your processes which you are doing inside your function gets completed within 30 seconds. Missing of proper exception handling might also lead to a timeout. You can also try the background functions and Circuits in Zoho Catalyst if you have processes which are long running.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code, it's hard to tell, but make sure your closing out the result with res.end()